# Connect to redis server using socket.io-client without having node for react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, redis

Main goal is to use redis pub/sub in react-native without have middle server.

I am trying to find a solution to connect to redis sever in the network, without have another server in between.

As react-native has no redis client, I am trying to find alternative.

wanted to see if we can connect to redis server using socket.io-client.

I tried using socket.io-redis

```js
this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://192.168.3.1:6379');
    this.redisAdapter = this.socket.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: '192.168.3.1', port: 6379 }));
    this.socket.on('Channel1', this.onReceivedMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have build the redis client for react native .
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-redispubsub

we can use this till we get it working with socket id